# Extending the number of reference cells passed to .Range function in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I am using worksheet.range("Relevantcells") to copy cells in a sheet. I have non-contiguous cells and hence it only lets me put in 60 specific cells.

How can I extend this to many more cells that I want to read from?

Comment: Can you make is a little more clear what exactly it is you are trying to achieve? I am not sure what you mean at the moment...

Comment: At least in Excel 2007 you can define much more than 60 non-contiguous cells in a named ranged. Tested 120 without any problem

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having one large non-contiguous range, you could create an array of smaller ranges in code and then copy each range iteratively.

You'll likely take a performance hit over copying the ranges en masse, but this approach should be more flexible.